# How to find duplicates in one field which are not duplicates in another

Tags: mysql, sql, having

I'm trying to extract account numbers and postcodes from a table, where the postcodes are duplicates but the account numbers are not, (only where a postcode exists)

For example a table called `mailing` with the following fields:-

```
acc....custname.............postcode
B102...BILLYS SHOES.........LE54 2YZ
B104...BILLYS SHOES.........LE54 2YZ
D200...FANSY................RM5 6LW
D200...FANSY(2ND ACCOUNT)...RM5 6LW
T502...WELLIES R US.........
T502...WELLIES R US.........
    ...THE SHOE SHOP........DN54 05Y
X102...THE SHOE SHOP........DN54 05Y
```

So, i've tried to group by postcode having a count of > 1 which works fine, and displays

```
acc....custname.............postcode
B102...BILLYS SHOES.........LE54 2YZ
B104...BILLYS SHOES.........LE54 2YZ
D200...FANSY................RM5 6LW
D200...FANSY(2ND ACCOUNT)...RM5 6LW
    ...THE SHOE SHOP........DN54 05Y
X102...THE SHOE SHOP........DN54 05Y
```

but I need to be able to only display where the account number is also not duplicated, ie as below

```
acc....custname.............postcode
B102...BILLYS SHOES.........LE54 2YZ
B104...BILLYS SHOES.........LE54 2YZ
    ...THE SHOE SHOP........DN54 05Y
X102...THE SHOE SHOP........DN54 05Y
```

Code:

```
SELECT *
FROM mailing
WHERE postcode IS NOT NULL AND postcode <> '' AND
postcode IN (SELECT postcode FROM mailing group by postcode HAVING COUNT(postcode) > 1)
ORDER BY postcode;
```

Have tried to use another counter on the account number but don't get any data back at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` and `EXISTS` for the 2 conditions:

```
SELECT m.* FROM mailing m
WHERE
  NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM mailing
    WHERE acc = m.acc AND custname <> m.custname
  )
  AND
  EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM mailing
    WHERE postcode = m.postcode and acc <> m.acc
  )
```

If you just want *records where postcodes are duplicated, but only if they're for different account numbers* then use only EXISTS:

```
SELECT m.* FROM mailing m
WHERE
  EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM mailing
    WHERE postcode = m.postcode and acc <> m.acc
  )
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I'm not sure how this works as it seems to bring back varying data. Can this be modified to NOT compare the custname field. So basically I just want it to bring back records where postcodes are duplicated, but only if they're for different account numbers, thanks

Comment: @CR15BRN if this answer solved your problem consider accepting it by ticking the checkmark at the left.